# Why Ohm's law is followed inside the house?

Tags: everyday-life, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

In power transmission lines, as power remains constant, according to $P=VI$, current decreases when voltage increases, thus Ohm's law is not followed. But inside our house current increases when voltage increases. Thus Ohm's law is being followed. But why?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE :) Please elaborate a bit more as to what exactly is your question.

Comment: The obvious answer is that inside the house voltage is fixed while current varies.  In neither case is Ohm's Law necessary.

Comment: Power in transmission lines does not remain constant. Why would you think that it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How easy it is to get confused about these things.

Ohm's law applies to a resistive load - describing that a higher voltage will lead to more current flowing (and therefore, more power being dissipated. A fresh battery will make the light of your flashlight shine brighter.)

When we look at power transmission lines, the question becomes "How can I transmit as much power as possible with the least amount of loss". For the power line, there are two different voltages of interest.

One is the "transmitted" voltage $V_t$; the other is the "dropped" voltage, $V_d$. Now the goal is to get $V_t$ to the other side of the power line. But since the line has resistance $R$, the current $I$ flowing will lead to a voltage drop

$$V_d = I\cdot R$$

At the other end of the transmission line there's a big load (transformer, whatever) which is where the bulk of the energy will be used. But when we think about the power losses in the cable, we care that "most of the power makes it through unharmed".

[image]

When you are talking about electricity in your house, you consider the load as part of the equation; when you are thinking about the power transmission, you are interested in minimizing just $V_d$. Does that help?

Comment: You have tried to explain it but the answer is not clear.